# Scep server reports wrong tag in my csr request

Tags: openssl, certificate, scep

I'm trying to get a certificate from a SCEP Server. I prepared a CSR using openssl.

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.csr
```

Here's my CSR:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Now, when I send that to the SCEP Server, I'm getting an error in response:

> asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:0 tag:2 length:1 isCompound:false}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false private:false defaultValue: tag: stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} tbsCertificateRequest @2

I looked a bit into ASN.1 tags table (https://www.obj-sys.com/asn1tutorial/node124.html) and source code of Go SCEP Server (https://golang.org/src/encoding/asn1/asn1.go) (look for "tags don't match") and I understand that the server expected to see a SEQUENCE and instead it got an INTEGER.

I used a [ASN.1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIIC-TCCAeECAQAwgZUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlBMMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpTb21lLVN0YXRlMRMwEQYDVQQHEwpXYXJyaW5ndG9uMRIwEAYDVQQKEwlNeUNvbXBhbnkxDzANBgNVBAsTBk15VW5pdDERMA8GA1UEAxMIU29tZU5hbWUxJDAiBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWFWRldmVsb3BlckBjb21wYW55LmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAJyfp-vXLET-cXhXlcP61jQPw2-34kEij36_CeR6qAt4h827o28OsyTJ0hLTej7HlwVO4j0Hj9bngdt9bGtCdkx3jtEEVBKrhwD0ZAVP4MTkAEAjoS4SA55YBVCQevTTyWxD7yYQDtcg7lg5blsAISXTH5-bO1qgyvAthb1DpcztIYymOB3iw74-pFMNzcatbFPKeNJMo75fHdEagUr6nHaSmdPRMfkvupbU5j3DQ6TSl8dPG4FEJBzIlMm0q-_y8F-qmQgac_vkzUiNCF36Iro9eWvuZ5N9z0fpVWDfaKLKwj6oFTL9U4z9KjnUk8mM4peSA71d9iLMd-I-CFcZzx0CAwEAAaAeMBwGCSqGSIb3DQEJBzEPEw1Tb21lQ2hhbGxlbmdlMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQBeMCQb8meAL3LVqYMMGrt2WuNfKviw_HGVygiFN9E0AdO_6OEYiERo9bRq1PFToTtzN6BDm96lIUdexczYNBMQssjWC1qTOHKKttLK0FUuhQtoZJTGnB4VTjiuBStQtGx-8OIULlJoCwFJUAMUqzllAs60oT8QTLbfeoyRZOhOmK6b0_9l6sH1ltfULjNyOiDuIeUfzyWzk3zWZEq-iFx59U5giLnlCKMRhlYx3FIXRkboCeqEhnelU4KqPK9PmrzhdFHpiTzFIs3AnLXD8HOcmMSEuHvoibbB4rPHpiZ6q9rjSAJefOjk-0o6kJrj_FoD0JWDKJkqyslSfY31QYtL) and I saw that in the structure there is some INTEGER with VALUE=0:
[image]

//EDIT: Probably it's just a CSR version (always 0)

I do not know what is its purpose. I tried removing that integer, moving it to other place, however, nothing helped. I would be quite surprised if openSSL produced a wrong CSR. Do you maybe have some idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: I think that the integer value=0 that I have there is a version of CSR. With that, I run out of ideas what could be wrong there..

Comment: version = 0 is fine

Comment: `certutil -dump .\test.p10` can read the file. Seems to be an issue of the SCEP impelmentation...

Comment: @DanielFisherlennybacon I'm using https://github.com/micromdm/scep as a server

Comment: Have you filed an issue at github?

Comment: What is your SCEP client ?